# Custom ocmod modification not working in opencart version 3.0.2.0

Tags: php, mysql, opencart-3

I have successfully uploaded my customised .ocmod folder(.ocmode.zip) in the extension installer and got success message too. But this is not loading in the extensions.
I'm using opencart Version 3.0.3.2.

My files are in the structure:
 - upload
     - admin
     - catalog

Is there an alternative way to approach this? 
Please help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The issue is solved. It was a silly mistake. The folder structure was wrong.
The image folder was missing inside the admin folder, it is mandatory to keep the image folder even though there is no image inside it.

Comment: it is not mentioned anywhere that 'image' folder is mandatory in ocmod folder. There are plenty of ocmod extensions working without 'image' folder

Answer (score 2):

I was also having the same issue. Everything was right and it shows success message but it does not show in the Modification lists. I found this video and the solution is at https://youtu.be/NCtiqTyEoUA?t=597 I was zipping the main folder than zipping the upload/ folder and install.xml file.

Once I select upload/ folder and install.xml and then zip it and rename it to  ***.ocmod.xml, it shows up in Modification lists.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload manually, but have you made changes using install.xml file?

Comment: If i put all the files manually in those folders that i needed, it will work. But i need this as a .zip and to be installed through the Extension Installer section.

Comment: Also i have made changes in .xml filles also. Still not showing in extension listing

Comment: <file path="catalog/language/en-gb/common/footer.php">
        <operation>
            <search>
            <![CDATA[
            $_['text_powered']      = 'Powered By <a href="http://www.opencart.com">OpenCart</a><br /> %s &copy; %s';
            ]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
            $_['text_powered']      = 'Powered By <a href="http://www.facebook.com/">Tmailtester</a><br /> %s &copy; %s';
            ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>

Comment: You are missing xml tag

Comment: I haven't missed the xml tag.. its inside the tag(because of this comment box limitation i have omitted it).

Comment: see this https://github.com/settysantu/mintleaf/blob/master/install.xml you will understand.

Comment: Can u share full code on github or on some other like paste it.. so i can see code and help u

Comment: Ok. You should encoding of the files convert to UTF-8 for example using Notepad++ This should help.XML file does not mater because it not have any important information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm using netbeans and by default it is utf8.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Encoding of the files you should convert to UTF-8 for example using Notepad++ This should help.XML file does not mater in your case, because it not have any important information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I'm using netbeans and by default it is utf8.

Comment: @sreeja I don't know what are you using, but I have checked your files and there ANSI. After I have converted to UTF-8 files uploading using OC default installer...